# Design pattern for converting data to one of multiple types [Scala]

Tags: scala, generics

I have an iterator that I would like to allow clients to format in different types. For example, I'd like to have an interface that looks like:

```
val results = new Results[Integer](Seq(1,2,3,4))  
results.foreach(print)     // Prints 1, 2, 3, 4

val jsResults = results.as[JsArray]
jsResults.foreach(print)   // Prints [ [1], [2], [3], [4] ] 

results.as[String].foreach(print)  // Prints "1", "2", "3", "4"
results.as[HTML].foreach(print)    // Prints <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td>...</tr>
```

What is an elegant class design to implement this? The approach I'm taking is an abstract Results class with subclasses for each result type. So something like:

```
abstract class Results[T](...)
class JsonResults extends Results[JsArray]
class StringResults extends Results[String]
class HTMLResults extends Results[HTML]
```

But I'm having trouble implementing a function on the `abstract class Results` to return the correct subclass given a result type. This is what I have so far, but I'm getting all types of compile errors:

```
abstract class Results[T](...) {
   def as[A : ClassTag]: Result[A] = implicitly[ClassTag[A]] = {
      case implicitly[ClassTag[JsArray]] => new JsonResults(...)
      ...
   }
}
```

Errors look like:

```
[error]  found   : JsonResults
[error]  required: Result[A]
[error]     case implicitly[ClassTag[JsArray]] => new JsonResults(...)
```

Let me know if there's anything I can clarify.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to accomplish. Do you just want different ways to format results? If so, what is wrong with a number of simple methods that takes a Results[T] and returns a string? Or do you want to define implicit conversions that can be accessed using a method so they are not as dangerous as real implicit conversions?

Comment: the compiler is not smart enough to get that matching `implicitly[ClassTag[JsArray]]` implies that `A` is `JsArray`, so it cannot know that `JsonResults` is a `Result[A]`, hence the error. But you know it is, so you can cast by hand...

Comment: This is almost certainly an overcomplication without practical purpose. Solving this would definitely incur a performance overhead due to escape to reflection. Just use simple methods like `asJSON` or `asString`.

Answer (score 0):

You are heading toward right direction with using implicits for constructing type classes.

You may see example in excellent sjson library.

- documentation: https://github.com/debasishg/sjson/wiki/Typeclass-based-JSON-Serialization
- abstract classes: https://github.com/debasishg/sjson/blob/master/src/main/scala/sjson/json/Protocol.scala
- class methods: https://github.com/debasishg/sjson/blob/master/src/main/scala/sjson/json/JsonSerialization.scala
- some class instances: https://github.com/debasishg/sjson/blob/master/src/main/scala/sjson/json/Primitives.scala https://github.com/debasishg/sjson/blob/master/src/main/scala/sjson/json/StandardTypes.scala

Given example is parametrized over type from which the conversion is performed. You should add second parametrization over target type:

```
trait Writes[T, R] {
  def writes(o: T): R
}

def serialize[T,R](o: T)(implicit wrt: Writes[T,R]): R = wrt.writes(o)
```

And you should write realization for according protocols, as in the examples linked above